# Getting error: 'component' does not exist in type 'FormControlProps'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

I am able to set `{ component: "fieldset", ...param }` to `FormControlProps`:

```
const Temp = () => {
  const param: FormControlProps = {};
  
  // Able to set `{ component: "fieldset", ...param }` to `FormControlProps`:
  <FormControl {...{ component: "fieldset", ...param }} />;
};
```

But not able to do same thing through the `CustomFormControl`:

```
interface ICustomFormControlProps {
  customFormControlProps: FormControlProps; // lets keep them same for some reason
}

const CustomFormControl = (param: ICustomFormControlProps) => {
  return <FormControl {...param.customFormControlProps} />; // so, basically CustomFormControl is same as FormControl
};

const CustomFormControlVariant1 = (param2: ICustomFormControlProps) => {
  return (
    <CustomFormControl
      customFormControlProps={{
        component: "fieldset", // Error occurs here
        ...param2.customFormControlProps
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

It gives me following error:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' does not exist in type 'FormControlProps<"div", {}>'
```

Why is this so?

[here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ardinghelli-fnoj15?file=/src/temp.tsx)

**Update**

I just tried similar thing with `Grid` and it works:

```
import { Grid, GridProps } from "@mui/material";

interface ICustomControlProps {
  gridProps?: GridProps;
}

const CustomControl = (props: ICustomControlProps) => {
  return <Grid {...props.gridProps}></Grid>;
};

const CustomControlVariant1 = (props: ICustomControlProps) => {
  return (
    <CustomControl
      gridProps={{ item: true, xs: 12, sm: 12, md: 12, ...props.gridProps }}  // why this doesnt give any error at all?
    />
  );
};
```

[`temp3.tsx` in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ardinghelli-fnoj15?file=/src/temp3.tsx:0-401)

Comment: Because that's not the same thing. In your `Temp` example, `FormControlProps` is the type given to your `param` constant, not the type of the object literal that you spread into `FormControl` (which just happens to have `param` spread into it).

Comment: **Q1.** So, to imitate same in `CustomFormControl`, I should do something like this: `formControlProps={{...{ component: "fieldset", ...props.formControlProps }}}`, right? (As I done in [Temp2.tsx of codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ardinghelli-fnoj15?file=/src/temp2.tsx)? ) **Q2.** But then, why doing something similar with `Grid` control for `GridProps` works? I mean why this works: `gridProps={{ item: true, xs: 12, sm: 12, md: 12, ...props.gridProps }}`? Please find this example in the update I made at the end of the original question.